# Gerar aleatoriamente no formato XXXX-0000

Tags: javascript

Como gerar uma string aleatoriamente no formato `XXXX-0000` onde `X` pode ser uma letra ou número? O que consegui até agora foi o seguinte:

```
var letra = String.fromCharCode(65+Math.floor(Math.random() * 26))
var numero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
```

Gera uma letra, e um número aleatório. Porém, não sei fazer um laço disso para ficar no formato que quero.

Comment: Os `0000` são fixos ou é o local onde vai gerar numeros ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Segundo a pergunta, o que se deseja é que os 4 primeiros caracteres
>   sejam **alfanuméricos** e os 4 últimos **apenas numéricos**:

```
          ┌──────┐   ┌──────┐
          │ XXXX │ - │ 0000 │
          └──────┘   └──────┘
              ↑         ↑
     alfanuméricos     numéricos
(números ou letras)
```

Você pode usar a variável `numero` para alternar randomicamente a concatenação entre *letra* ou *número*, verificando se `numero` é par: **se for *par*, concatena uma letra; se for *ímpar*, concatena um número**.

Use um laço `for` para gerar os 8 caracteres (*4 alfanuméricos + 4 númericos*):

```js
for(var x=1, alfanum = num = ""; x<5; x++){
   var letra = String.fromCharCode(65+Math.floor(Math.random() * 26));
   var numero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
   var numero2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
   alfanum += numero%2 == 0 ? letra : numero; // verifico se 'numero' é par para formar a sequência alfanumérica
   num += numero2; // formo a sequência numérica
}
console.log(alfanum+"-"+num);
```

Answer (score 5):

Você não precisa utilizar estruturas de repetição para gerar valores alfanuméricos. Basta usar uma base na função `toString`, por exemplo:

```js
let first = Math.random()       // Gera um valor randômico
                .toString(36)   // Utiliza a Base36
                .substr(-4)     // Captura os 4 últimos números
                .toUpperCase(); // Converte para maiúscula 
                
let last = Math.floor((Math.random() * (9999 - 1000)) + 1000); // Gera um valor entre 999 e 10000

console.log( `${first}-${last}` )
```

> A [Base36](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_numera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_hexatrigesimal) é um sistema numérico formado por algarismos arábicos de 0 a 9 e de letras do alfabeto latino de A à Z, ex: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z (lembre-se que as letras podem ser maiúsculas ou minúsculas).

```js
for (let num = 0; num <= 35; num++) {
  var a = num.toString();   // Decimal
  var b = num.toString(2);  // Binário
  var c = num.toString(8);  // Octal
  var d = num.toString(16); // Hexadecimal
  var e = num.toString(36); // Hexatrigesimal

  var n = a + " | " + b + " | " + c + " | " + d + " | " + e + "<br><br>";

  document.body.innerHTML += n;
}
```

Comment: A idéia é uma das melhores, mas seria bom ajustar o seu random pra começar de 10000 **em base 36**, (que é 1679616) para garantir pegar sempre 4 digitos (e fazer o mesmo no last)

Answer (score 1):

Uma abordagem funcional seria assim:

```
const geraAlpha = () => {
  return String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26))
}

const geraNumero = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
}

const reduce = Array(4).fill(0).reduce(prev => {
  return {
    alpha: prev.alpha + geraAlpha(), 
    numero: prev.numero+ geraNumero()
  }
}, {alpha: '', numero: ''})

console.log(`${reduce.alpha}-${reduce.numero}`)
```